# Replacing question marks and equal signs with htaccess

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, url, url-rewriting

I'm trying to replace question marks and equal signs so that I can use URLs like the following:

http://www.mydomain.com/categories/id/23/name/category-name

The above url would be internally redirected to 
http://www.mydomain.com/categories?id=23&name=category-name

I am using this .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

# external redirect from /view.php?id=1 to /view/id/1
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+([^.]+)\.php\?([^=]+)=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2/%3? [L,R=301]

# internal forward from /view/id/1 to /view.php?id=1
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

but it's not working as expected. When I go to http://www.mydomain.com/categories/id/23/name/category-name I get a 500 internal server error. Why? What am I doing wrong?

***updated code***

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}\.php -f 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1.php

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ $1/$2=$3&$4 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?$2 [L,QSA]
```

Comment: Look into the webservers error.log for specifics on that 500.

Comment: what do your apache error logs say?

Comment: It says 'Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.' Looks like I have an infinite loop somehow?

Comment: Where is you htaccess file?

Comment: it's in the site folder (http://www.mydomain.com/.htaccess or C:/xampp/htdocs/mydomain.com/.htaccess)

Comment: Even without the error, `http://www.mydomain.com/categories/id/23/name/category-name` would never match because you have limited your pattern to only 3 `/` and one optional. So it would match only  `http://www.mydomain.com/categories/id/23/` at best and after that when you rewrite your first rule will most likely loop to death.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This rule should take care of recursively replacing each `/` with `=` and finally making it a nice Query String:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ $1/$2=$3&$4 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)$ $1.php?$2 [L,QSA]
```

You need to comment out or delete this rule:

```
# RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ /$1.php?$2=$3 [L,QSA]
```

**UPDATE:** You .htaccess need re-ordering and little bit of tweaking. This should work:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /mydomain/

RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?(.*)$ $1/$2=$3&$4 [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/(.+?)&?$ $1.php?$2 [L,QSA] 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME}.php -f
RewriteRule ^(.+?)/?$ $1.php [L]
```

Comment: this gives me the sames issue: 'Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace.' and the browser shows '[an error occurred while processing this directive]'

Comment: I have tested this code before posting. Post your complete .htaccess again please.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I updated my original question with the full code after your suggestions.

Comment: Ok thanks let me test with your complete code and get back to you.

Comment: After that reordering I get a 404 on all my pages... Why? I don't get it... On my error log I have stuff like: 'File does not exist C:/xampp/htdocs/mydomain/categories'

Comment: Does categories.php exist in Document_ROOT ?

Comment: Yes... If I go back to my original .htaccess and only use the first 5 lines, there are no issues (although that .htaccess doesn't replace question marks or equal signs, it just allows the non-inclusion of the php extension).

Comment: I have tested it again with URL like this: `http://localhost/categories/id/23/name/category-name` and it invokes `http://localhost/categories.php?id=23&name=category-name` internally.

Comment: hmmm maybe that's why? because I guess it should invoke localhost/mydomain... maybe a RewriteBase issue? Not sure...

Comment: What what is the URL you used to test this?

Comment: Hmm so there is `mydomain` before categories. Let me edit it then.